# Layer error: reduce.median: Error in map(ID=20200526T144731_20200526T145503_T19LFJ): Element.copyProperties: The source parameter is required

Tags: google-earth-engine

This code was working normally and now it's giving this error, does anyone know what changed?

https://code.earthengine.google.com/db01303623e6f1a4d0e417f1c3c0713e

The following errors appear:

```
print bands:
List (Error) reduce.median: Error in map(ID=20200526T144731_20200526T145503_T19LFJ):
Element.copyProperties: The source parameter is required.

RGB Lago Amapá: Layer error: reduce.median: Error in map(ID=20200526T144731_20200526T145503_T19LFJ):
Element.copyProperties: The source parameter is required.

pan-sharpened: Layer error: reduce.median: Error in map(ID=20200526T144731_20200526T145503_T19LFJ):
Element.copyProperties: The source parameter is required.

/////////STUDY SITE 

var inpe = ee.FeatureCollection("users/dfadeljunior/ucs_INPE_2020");
//print(inpe)
var LE = inpe.filterMetadata('NOME_UC1', 'equals', 'ÁREA DE PROTEÇÃO AMBIENTAL LAGO DO AMAPÁ')


/////////SENTINEL - 2 DATA

/******************************************ÍNDICES FENOLÓGICOS E DE ÁGUA*************************************/                       
function f_index_ (image) {
  var ndvi =  image.normalizedDifference(['B8','B4']).rename('NDVI');// Rouse 1973
  var evi = image.expression('2.5 * ((N - R) / (N + (6 * R) - (7.5 * B) + 1))', { //Huete 2002
        'N': image.select('B8'), 'R': image.select('B4'), 'B': image.select('B2')}).rename('EVI')
  var mndwi = image.normalizedDifference(['B3', 'B12']).rename('MNDWI'); // Xu 2005
  var ndwi = image.normalizedDifference(['B3', 'B8']).rename ('NDWI'); //Mc Feeters 1996
  return image.addBands([ndvi, evi, mndwi, ndwi])}

var inBands = ee.List(['QA60','B1','B2','B3','B4','B5','B6','B7','B8','B8A','B9','B11','B12']);
var outBands = ee.List(['QA60','cb','blue','green','red','re1','re2','re3','nir','re4','waterVapor','swir1','swir2']);
 
var CloudCoverMax = 1; //Vá alterando aqui até encontrar imagem adequada
var startDate = "2020-05-01";
var endDate = "2020-07-24";
var studyArea = LE;

// Get Sentinel-2 data
var s2 = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2_SR') //or COPERNICUS/S2
           .filterDate(startDate,endDate)
           .filterBounds(studyArea)
           .filter(ee.Filter.lt('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE',CloudCoverMax))
           .filter(ee.Filter.lt('CLOUD_COVERAGE_ASSESSMENT',CloudCoverMax))
           .map(f_index_);


// scale the data  (10 metros de resolução com 0,001 de escala  = 10000, portanto divide por 10000)
var scaleData = function scaleBands(img){
  var prop = img.toDictionary();
  var myImg = img.select(['B1','B2','B3','B4','B5','B6','B7','B8','B8A','B9','B11','B12']).divide(10000);
      myImg = myImg.addBands(img.select(['QA60'])).set(prop).copyProperties(img,['system:time_start','system:footprint']);
  return ee.Image(myImg);
};
var sentinel2 = s2.map(scaleData).select(inBands, outBands);


var s2VisParam = {"opacity":1,"bands":["red","green","blue"],"min":0.016,"max":0.175,"gamma":1.6};
Map.addLayer(sentinel2.median().clip(LE), s2VisParam, 'RGB Lago Amapá'); //10 m resolution - Natural Color

// Convert the RGB bands to the HSV color space.
var s2b = sentinel2.median().clip(LE)
var hsv = s2b.select(['red', 'green', 'blue']).rgbToHsv(); //'blue','green','red'
//print(hsv)
//Swap in the panchromatic band and convert back to RGB.
var sharpened = ee.Image.cat([
  hsv.select('hue'), hsv.select('saturation'), s2b.select('nir')
]).hsvToRgb();
// Display the pan-sharpened result.
Map.addLayer(sharpened,
             {min: 0.150, max: 0.355, gamma: [1.3, 1.3, 1.3]},
             'pan-sharpened');
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what the specific issue it here, but in general, [`copyProperties`](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/apidocs/ee-feature-copyproperties) can be avoided when you are scaling bands and wanting to retain the image's metadata by overwriting the original bands (set the `overwrite` parameter of [`ee.Image.addBands`](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/apidocs/ee-image-addbands) to `true`). Whenever possible, this is a better practice than copying properties. Your scaling function would be something like the following (untested).

```js
var scaleData = function scaleBands(img){
  var refl = img.select('B.*').divide(10000);
  return img.addBands(refl, null, true).select('B.*|QA60');
};
```